# Trying to parse a simple string and print word by word, getting Bus Error: 10

Tags: c

As the title indicates, this should be very easy. I don't understand why, but I'm getting a Bus error: 10 when I run this.

This should be so easy! But I can't seem to solve it.... ugh. Please help.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

main() {

char *string[20];
char buffer[256];

int wordCount = 0;

    while ((scanf("%s", buffer) != EOF)) {
        printf("%s%d\n", buffer, wordCount);
        string[wordCount++] = (char *) malloc (strlen(buffer)+1); 
        strcpy (string[wordCount], buffer);
    }

int j;

printf("There are %d words.\n", wordCount+1);

for (j = 0; j < wordCount; j++)
{

    printf("%s\n", string[j]);
}   
}
```

Comment: [Don't cast the return value of malloc() in C](http://stackoverflow.com/a/605858/28169).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> ```
> string[wordCount++] = (char *) malloc (strlen(buffer)+1); 
> strcpy (string[wordCount], buffer);
> ```

You're allocating to `string[wordCount]` and then you're incrementing `wordCount`. Then you proceed to `strcpy` to this new, unallocated element, which is illegal.

Increment `wordCount` **after** `strcpy` instead.

Answer (score 0):

Another problem you should have is that if you read more than 20 lines, you will make an illegal memory access since you are declaring an array of char pointers with 20 positions:

char *string[20];

You should reconsider the loop:

while ((scanf("%s", buffer) != EOF))

Answer (score 0):

You should ever check for an array-(index)-overflow like:

```
int main() {

char *string[20];
char buffer[256];

int j, wordCount = 0;

    while (wordcount<20 && (scanf("%255s", buffer) == 1)) {  /* here */
        printf("%s%d\n", buffer, wordCount+1);
        strcpy( string[wordCount++] = malloc (strlen(buffer)+1, buffer ); 
    }

printf("There are %d words.\n", wordCount+1);

for (j = 0; j < wordCount; j++)
{

    printf("%s\n", string[j]);
}
  return 0;
}
```

Note that scanf will ever breaks on all whitespaces and you clear the input-buffer after all scanf/fgets(stdin) actions.